# Tool for Cryptographic Message Syntax

Tags: linux, cms, encryption, file-format, cryptography

I am looking for a software tool (preferably command line, open source and running on Linux) which is able to comprehensively handle the *Cryptographic Message Syntax* (CMS) standard (formerly known as PKCS#7). I am aware, that there is `openssl cms`, but this can handle only a very little subset of the capabilities of CMS.